# Product of two algebras with maximum condition

Tags: universal-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two algebras of the same signature, both having maximum condition on sub-algebras. Is it true that $A\times B$ has the same property?

Comment: What is maximum condition?

Comment: Take ${\mathbb Z}$ with two unary operations $i:z\mapsto z+1$ and $d:z\mapsto z-1$. Such an algebra has only two subalgebras $\varnothing$ and ${\mathbb Z}$. Whereas in ${\mathbb Z}\times{\mathbb Z}$, a subalgebra is any subset closed with respect to the action of the group $({\mathbb Z},+)$ given by $z\cdot(z_1,z_2):=(z+z_1,z+z_2)$. Any orbit is given by the number $z_1-z_2$. Therefore, a subalgebra is nothing but a collection of integer numbers. Consequently, the maximality condition does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a semigroup example.

Take the semigroup $\mathbb Z_+$ of positive integers. Each of its subsemigroups is finitely generated so it has the maximum condition on subsemigroups.  But $\mathbb Z_+\times \mathbb Z_+$ is not finitely generated so it does not have the maximum condition.

Indeed, any element of the form $(m,1)$ with $m>0$ is not a sum of two elements of $\mathbb Z_+\times \mathbb Z_+$.  Thus these elements must belong to any generating set.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that determining the type of algebras having this property must be hard.